# Parsing dice notation with Elm

Tags: elm, parser-combinators

I am trying to write a small dice notation (e.g. "2d6", where `2` is the `count` and `6` is the die `size`) parser using the library in `elm-tools/parser`.

An expression should be in the form

```
[int] "d" int
```

but I can't figure out to parse the optional leading `int` (which will default to `1` if it is missing).

So far, I've come up with this:

```
import Parser exposing (..)


type alias Roll =
    { count : Int
    , size : Int
    }


die : Parser Int
die =
    succeed identity
        |. keyword "d"
        |= int
```

and I would like the parser to return a `Roll` on a successful parse, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I am guessing that I will need to make use of `oneOf`, but I'm not sure how.

Unfortunately, I can't find any good examples of using this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Chad's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620875/96233), I got it working with this:

```
type alias Dice =
    { count : Int
    , size : Int
    }


dice : Parser Dice
dice =
    succeed Dice
        |= count
        |. spaces
        |. keyword "d"
        |. spaces
        |= integer


count : Parser Int
count =
    oneOf
        [ integer |> andThen succeed
        , succeed 1
        ]


integer : Parser Int
integer =
    keep oneOrMore isDigit
        |> andThen
            (\s ->
                case String.toInt s of
                    Ok value ->
                        succeed value

                    Err err ->
                        fail err
            )


spaces : Parser ()
spaces =
    ignore zeroOrMore (\c -> c == ' ')
```

Comment: This answer [does not parse the original example you gave of `"2d6"`](https://ellie-app.com/3YVLMkCqM6ra1/0), since `int` fails if it hits an alphanumeric character. It would, however, succeed if you had a space after `2`. Did you change the requirements?

Comment: No. I am fixing the code now with a "private" `integer` parser instead of `int`. It seems that `int` gets confused on the `d` because it is a legal hex digit.

Comment: If Chad's answer helped you, you should upvote it and maybe accept it as the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could first write a parser that optionally parses an int and if nothing is consumed, then return a default value:

```elm
optionalInt : Int -> Parser Int
optionalInt default =
    keep zeroOrMore Char.isDigit
        |> andThen
            (\str ->
                case str of
                    "" ->
                        succeed default

                    digits ->
                        case String.toInt digits of
                            Ok val ->
                                succeed val

                            Err err ->
                                fail err
            )
```

Now you can use that parser to create a parser for `Roll`:

```elm
roll : Parser Roll
roll =
    succeed Roll
        |= optionalInt 1
        |. keyword "d"
        |= int
```

Comment: Correct on the `count` and `size`. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed my statement about ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

`Parser.keyword` fails you because it backtracks. You can use a raw `Parser.token` and get away with it. ([example on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/8Mc2C8tKH6La1))

```
dice : Parser (Int, Int)
dice =
    succeed Tuple.pair
        |= int
        |. Parser.token "d"
        |= int
```